# how to make input tag fill a whole <td> in a table with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good morning,

code here : http://jsbin.com/uhuqog/4/

In a `table`, when clicking on a `<td>` with `.editable` class, the original content of this `<td>` is replaced by an `<input type="text">` with the original content as the `value`.
I would like the input tag to have the same size of the original `<td>`. I tried to remove some margin and padding applied to the input tag but it didn't work and the `<td>` 's height and width change when changing input's height and width.

Comment: `width: 100%` but your table cells size will change based on the contents length so now you have two variable lengths, this is bound to go wrong somewhere.

Comment: what does that mean ?

Comment: if both have a variable length, what will the absolute length be? how will it be generated, you wont know so it will probably go wrong somewhere: the table cell will grow bigger when the content gets bigger so the question is: how wide will the table cell get before it wont get bigger, or does the browser use another way to calculate the table cell width...

Comment: You could try adding the class "input-block-level" to the input.

Comment: You should add classes to your table columns so you can set the widths in your style sheet, this way when the content changes the width of your cell won't

Answer (score 0):

I chose a different approach.

When the `<td>` is clicked, I calculate its absolute position, its width and height and I place the input above it.